# Play up to 9 videos simultaneously

Tags: video

I am looking for a program that can play up to 9 videos simultaneously in the same window (16 would be even better). If possible, free and works with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. I don't want to have to [pre-process](http://www.movavi.com/support/how-to/how-to-make-a-split-screen-video.html) the videos to make a single split-screen video. It support the most common video formats.

E.g. (with 4 videos):

[image]

For YouTube videos, I can use http://www.swigview.com

Comment: I know that with VLC and MPC-HC you can open multiple videos at once, but that's not all in one window.

Comment: Yeah it's a bit painful to open videos one by one and manually organize them (though there might be some software for the latter, I'll probably ask a bit later)

Comment: I know you don't want pre-process but..  https://youtu.be/Fv-hLeCUfCk?t=3m48s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Awesome Video Player.](http://www.awesomevideoplayer.com/)  It supports up to 16 videos played simultaneously.  Of course, performance will be better with fewer videos or on a more powerful computer.

[image: Awesome Video Player displaying 16 videos at once]

> AVPlayer supports playing multiple videos simultaneously, up to 16 videos at once on each screen! With automatic hardware and software decoding acceleration support. It plays absolutely every video format out there, at lightening fast speed too. Best of all, it’s 100% Free for awesome people like you!

Comment: Can't play a video in the correct orientation – neither reads an orientation tag nor has an option for video rotation.

Answer (score 0):

[GridPlayer](https://github.com/vzhd1701/gridplayer) can do this. No limit on the number of videos. It also has two decoding modes. You can run it on Windows, Linux or MacOS.

Full disclosure: I am the author.

[image]

> Simple VLC-based media player that can play multiple videos at the
> same time. You can play as many videos as you like, the only limit is
> your hardware. It supports all video formats that VLC supports (which
> is all of them). You can save your playlist retaining information
> about the position, sound volume, loops, aspect ratio, etc.