# Playing multiple video files side by side

Tags: windows, video, media-player

I need to play two (or more) video files synchronously.

The window should be split into two (or more) parts, in each part I want to play a different video file. And I want to control (start, pause, stop) playback of all of these files synchronously, there should be buttons to control all files at once.

Comment: This might be helpful, although it's not a ready-to-install program: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58104/beamer-media9-play-multiple-videos-at-once

Comment: See also: [Play up to 9 videos simultaneously](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/9883/60)

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using [Movavi](http://www.movavi.com/) video editor.

[Here is the link to tutorial on how to split videos into a single window.](http://www.movavi.com/support/how-to/how-to-make-a-split-screen-video.html)

If you want to do that online for Youtube videos,you can use [SwigView](http://www.swigview.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but tshis programm crops both videos...

Comment: It has to definitely crop because when you want multiple videos to play in a single window,every video has to fit according to the available resolution for that video.So,unless the video is cropped to fit to resolution of part of window it becomes difficult for the player to play high resolution window on a low resolution screen.Some complicated algorithm needs to be implemented to serve that purpose of playing high resolution video on a low resolution screen.Otherwise your purpose can't be met.

Answer (score 0):

[VLC](http://videolan.org). Has a wiki which includes instruction on [how to play video files](https://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_play_multiple_instances_of_VLC/).

But synchronously controlling them?
Don't know about that. You can try by editing the configuration file, but I can't say it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying the [Valt Multi Video Player](http://ipivs.com/products/valt-multi-video-player/).

You can download it for either Windows or Mac.  It does exactly what you are looking and for plays up to 9 videos at the same time. The only drawback is it is only compatible with .mp4 files.

Comment: Still works, but uses Adobe Air (which is not discontinued yet). Has synchronized zooming, but not moving (both videos are moved at once). Can't read an orientation tag (will show vertical video overturned)

Answer (score 0):

VLC for Windows will let you do that. You can open two files and control them each asynchronously (two set of controls), or view two files side by side and control both synchronously (one set of controls).